# How should I trigger network call in SwiftUI app to refresh data on app open?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm writing a SwiftUI app, and I want it periodically refresh data from a server:

- when the app is first opened
- if the app enters the foreground and the data has not been updated in the past 5 minutes

Below is the code I have so far.

What is the best way to trigger this update code the first time the app is opened in a SwiftUI app? Is adding the observer in `onAppear` a good practice for triggering the update when the app enters the foreground? (This is the only view in the app)

```
class InfoStore {

    var lastValueCheck: Date = .distantPast
}

struct ContentView : View {

    var infoStore: InfoStore

    private func updateValueFromServer() {

        // request updated value from the server

        // if the request is successful, store the new value

        currentValue = 500
        UserDefaults.cachedValue = 500
        // hardcoded for this example

        infoStore.lastValueCheck = Date()
    }

    private func updateValueIfOld() {

        let fiveMinutesAgo: Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: (-5 * 60))

        if infoStore.lastValueCheck < fiveMinutesAgo {
            updateValueFromServer()
        }
    }

    @State var currentValue: Int = 100

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(currentValue)")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .onAppear {
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
                                                       object: nil,
                                                       queue: .main) { (notification) in
                    self.updateValueIfOld()
                }
        }
    }
}

extension UserDefaults {

    private struct Keys {
        static let cachedValue = "cachedValue"
    }

    static var cachedValue: Int {
        get {
            return standard.value(forKey: Keys.cachedValue) as? Int ?? 0
        }
        set {
            standard.set(newValue, forKey: Keys.cachedValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer to cover your second question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) About the first point (app first opened): probably the best way to get what you want is to extract the logic outside the View (as MVVM suggests) using `DataBinding` and `ObservableObject`s. I changed your code as less as possible in order to show you what I mean:

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentValue = -1
    private var lastValueCheck = Date.distantPast

    init() {
        updateValueFromServer()
    }

    func updateValueIfOld() {
        let fiveMinutesAgo: Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: (-5 * 60))

        if lastValueCheck < fiveMinutesAgo {
            updateValueFromServer()
        }
    }

    private func updateValueFromServer() {
        // request updated value from the server

        // if the request is successful, store the new value

        currentValue = 500
        UserDefaults.cachedValue = 500
        // hardcoded for this example

        lastValueCheck = Date()
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(viewModel.currentValue)")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .onAppear {
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
                                                       object: nil,
                                                       queue: .main) { (notification) in
                                                        self.viewModel.updateValueIfOld()
                }
        }
    }
}

extension UserDefaults {

    private struct Keys {
        static let cachedValue = "cachedValue"
    }

    static var cachedValue: Int {
        get {
            return standard.value(forKey: Keys.cachedValue) as? Int ?? 0
        }
        set {
            standard.set(newValue, forKey: Keys.cachedValue)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(viewModel: ViewModel())
    }
}
#endif
```

This way, as soon as the `ViewModel` is created the `currentValue` is updated. Also, every time `currentValue` is changed by a server call the UI is automatically recreated for you. Note that you have to modify the `sceneDelegate` this way:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView(viewModel: ViewModel()))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

2) About the second point (app enters foreground): you should be careful here because you're registering the observer multiple times (every time the `onAppear` is fired). Depending on your needs you should decide to:

- remove the observer `onDisappear` (this is very frequent)
- add the observer just one time checking if you have already added it.

In any case it's a good practice to implement the:

```
deinit {

}
```

method and eventually remove the observer.

Comment: I like the approach of checking whether the observer is added already to only add it once. To do that, I created a var in `ViewModel` called `foregroundObserverAdded`. At first I tried creating it right in `ContentView`, but I got an error when I tried to set it (after setting up the observer) because `ContentView` is a struct. Does this seem like a good solution, to put it in `ViewModel`, to get around that issue?

Comment: @gohnjanotis In order to have mutable state in a `View` you should use `@State` property wrapper. When you have some state that strictly belongs to the view itself (as in this case for that boolean value) you should write something like `@State private var addNotificationObserver = true` (always use `private` in this case to enforce that you are managing some state that belongs only to the view and it's not intended to be accessed by some other entities).